# Strech to constraint does not work as expected

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

I'm rigging the foot of the bird Piero training course of the `CG Cookie` and I get stuck on the rigging of the leg. I don't know how to explain the problem using the words,so I recorded a video. I'm on `minute 33.24` of the episode `26_piero_rigging_leg`. I tried to follow carefully what he did and I repeated the same steps a lot of times,but my result is not like his. The problem arise when I move the control bone `CTRL_dogLeg` with the `g key` because the bones linked to it with the location and stretch constraint moves too fast and they can't stop streching. This is what happens :

[video : bones seem to be crazy when I move the CTRL_dogLeg bone with g](https://sendvid.com/pco41bh4)

I also attach 3 screenshots to show you what's inside the bone constraints tab :

[image: bone constraints tab pic 1]
[image: bone constraints tab pic 2]
[image: bone constraints tab pic 3]

Comment: What do you expect it to work like?

Comment: I need to have more control over the control bone because whem i move it the stretched bones move too fast. Can you see it in the video ?